# Execution error when out-of stack enviroment, using text-icu on windows

Tags: windows, haskell, dll, icu, haskell-stack

I wrote some code. and fixed some errors with the help of good persons.
Now, this utility(samChecker-exe.exe) works properly in Stack environment.
This utility use text-icu and I coded this utility on windows. Of course, I want to work this utility on other windows OS.

I copied %stackPath%.stack-work\install\~\bin\samCheceker-exe.exe to some other folder, and execution through CMD.
But I got error message that says "libicuuc57.dll dose not exist. so program can't start. please re-install the program."
I copied libicuuc57.dll, and so... as like programming newbies, but failed. "stack install" command was the same result.
(I installed text-icu and installed ICU lib. on windows. The input file encoded in "MS949")

With help of Francesco Ariis from (beginners@haskell.org), I stepped forward.
But still got error message.

```
C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3> stack build  --ghc-options="-static -optl-static"
Warning: File listed in samChecker3.cabal file does not exist: README.md
samChecker3-0.1.0.0: unregistering (local file changes: app\Main.hs samChecker3.cabal src\Lib.hs test\Spec.hs)
samChecker3-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
Configuring samChecker3-0.1.0.0...
samChecker3-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Preprocessing library samChecker3-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Lib              ( src\Lib.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\Lib.o )
Preprocessing executable 'samChecker3-exe' for samChecker3-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app\Main.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\samChecker3-exe\samChecker3-exe-tmp\Main.o )
Linking .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\samChecker3-exe\samChecker3-exe.exe ...
C:/Users/shaeg/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/x86_64-windows/ghc-8.0.2/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licuuc
C:/Users/shaeg/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/x86_64-windows/ghc-8.0.2/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licuin
C:/Users/shaeg/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/x86_64-windows/ghc-8.0.2/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -licudt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
Warning: File listed in samChecker3.cabal file does not exist: README.md

--  While building package samChecker3-0.1.0.0 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab build lib:samChecker3 exe:samChecker3-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

[stack path] results

```
extra-include-dirs: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include
extra-library-dirs: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib
```

According to first error message(libicuuc57.dll dose not exist. so program can't start. please re-install the program.), I find the path for libicuuc57.dll, and re-set the extra-library-dirs.

```
C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3>stack build --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\bin --ghc-options="-static -optl-static"
```

But got the same result.

libicuuc75.dll, libicuin57.dll etc files is located in C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\bin

Someones says, this is Linker Acting.
How can I fix this error?
Thank you so much.

Sincerely, S. Chang.

---

Here is my stack path.

```
C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3>stack path
stack-root: C:\sr
project-root: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3
config-location: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3\stack.yaml
bin-path: .;C:\sr\snapshots\7dd4ddea\bin;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\mingw\bin;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\usr\bin;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\x64\Release\;C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelSGXPSW\bin\win32\Release\;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Roaming\local\bin;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
programs: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows
compiler-exe: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc.EXE
compiler-bin: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin
local-bin: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Roaming\local\bin
extra-include-dirs: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include
extra-library-dirs: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib
snapshot-pkg-db: C:\sr\snapshots\7dd4ddea\pkgdb
local-pkg-db: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3\.stack-work\install\02136e14\pkgdb
global-pkg-db: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\lib\package.conf.d
ghc-package-path: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3\.stack-work\install\02136e14\pkgdb;C:\sr\snapshots\7dd4ddea\pkgdb;C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\lib\package.conf.d
snapshot-install-root: C:\sr\snapshots\7dd4ddea
local-install-root: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3\.stack-work\install\02136e14
snapshot-doc-root: C:\sr\snapshots\7dd4ddea\doc
local-doc-root: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3\.stack-work\install\02136e14\doc
dist-dir: .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab
local-hpc-root: C:\Users\shaeg\Documents\Haskell\samChecker3\.stack-work\install\02136e14\hpc
local-bin-path: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Roaming\local\bin
ghc-paths: C:\Users\shaeg\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows
```

Comment: I can't test with `text-icu` for a private reason, but I would try replacing stack's msys to 20161025 revision and `pacman -Sy icu-devel`.
Of course build command should be done with msys shell.

Comment: And above one is for static linking. I don't know your error message after dll copying, but if it was additional dependency problem then dependency walker would be help.

Comment: I still try to resolve this... but don't work. I try to replace stack's msys, but fail. So I tyr to find another method. (ㅠ_ㅠ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test it recently, and share my solution.

First of all, I assume environment of latest msys2 which is installed `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu 57.1-2` package.

### Dynamic linking

Executable which dynamically linked has dependencies to `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll libicudt57.dll libicuin57.dll libicuuc57.dll libstdc++-6.dll libwinpthread-1.dll` under stack's msys2 `mingw64/bin` path. If you have already built dynamic linked executable, copying all of them to same directory will solve the problem.

[Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) in my comment can help to reveal all of these dependencies.

### Static linking

Currently `text-icu` package doesn't seem to support static linking. So we should modify it ourselves. If you don't know how to make it into local package, note the third option of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147218).

Modify `text-icu-0.7.0.1`'s .cabal file `extra-libraries` section to the following.

```
  extra-libraries: sicuin sicuuc sicudt
--  if os(mingw32)
--    extra-libraries: icuin icudt
--  else
--    extra-libraries: icui18n icudata
```

Append `-pgmlC:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\mingw\bin\g++.exe` to your executable's `ghc-options` cabal entry. This is required to link to ICU's C++ symbols.

Then just do `stack build`.

Comment: Thank you so much to your kind reply. Have a nice day~ =)