# For haskell stack I can't install Spock

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

For Stack, it gives me this error(see it below) when I try to use stack install for Spock.

I tried to install each one by themselves(individual packages) and it didn't work. 
I tried to follow with the answers in [Haskell Stack package installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142210/haskell-stack-package-installation-error) and that didn't work either.

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for Spock-0.13.0.0:
    Spock-core must match >=0.13, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest
               matching version is 0.13.0.0)
    reroute must match >=0.5, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
            version is 0.5.0.0)
    stm-containers must match >=0.2 && <0.3, but the stack configuration has no specified version
                   (latest matching version is 0.2.16)
needed since Spock is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some
    working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated
    constraint errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
    in C:\Windows\system32\stack.yaml:

Spock-core-0.13.0.0@sha256:06e007f23c47bdda52d2927da54160d73f1b6f51a977f3ca9087275698db8f0a
reroute-0.5.0.0@sha256:3360747cdc700c9808a38bff48b75926efa443d4af282396082329a218a8d9d3
stm-containers-0.2.16@sha256:e98efa8dcf0045ea8a78a04b4e2763cf2d8bc33aad0750e2f30a67f8f4e933b1

Plan construction failed.
```

I want to be installed without error.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoters would care to explain what they dislike about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important bit in this error is the following:

> In the dependencies for Spock-0.13.0.0: Spock-core must match >=0.13, but the stack configuration has no specified version

Basically, here is what is happening: The primary Haskell package repository is [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/). However, Stack gets its packages from its own repository, known as [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/). As the front page says:

> A Stackage snapshot includes pinned package versions from Hackage … It is a curated set of packages that work well together

However, Stackage has one major problem: it does not include every package in Hackage. This is indicated by the fact that that package has no specified version in the Stackage snapshot you are using. But that’s what Stack’s error message says! So in plain English, the error from Stack says that `Spock-core` is not included in your selected snapshot.

So, how do we fix this? Well, it is possible to manually tell Stack which package version to use. And in fact, the instructions for doing so are included in the error message:

> ```
>   * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
>    in C:\Windows\system32\stack.yaml:
>
> - Spock-core-0.13.0.0@sha256:06e007f23c47bdda52d2927da54160d73f1b6f51a977f3ca9087275698db8f0a
> - reroute-0.5.0.0@sha256:3360747cdc700c9808a38bff48b75926efa443d4af282396082329a218a8d9d3
> - stm-containers-0.2.16@sha256:e98efa8dcf0045ea8a78a04b4e2763cf2d8bc33aad0750e2f30a67f8f4e933b1
> ```

Here, `C:\Windows\system32\stack.yaml` is the path of your global Stack configuration file. To get rid of the error, you need to open that file and find a line starting with `extra-deps:`. Then, delete that line and replace it with the following information, taken from the error message:

```
extra-deps:
- Spock-core-0.13.0.0@sha256:06e007f23c47bdda52d2927da54160d73f1b6f51a977f3ca9087275698db8f0a
- reroute-0.5.0.0@sha256:3360747cdc700c9808a38bff48b75926efa443d4af282396082329a218a8d9d3
- stm-containers-0.2.16@sha256:e98efa8dcf0045ea8a78a04b4e2763cf2d8bc33aad0750e2f30a67f8f4e933b1
```

This informs Stack that you want to use version 0.13.0.0 of `Spock-core`, version 0.5.0.0 of `reroute`, and version 0.2.16 `stm-containers`. Normally Stack can figure this information out by itself using the information in the appropriate Stackage snapshot, but in this case the snapshot does not contain information about those three packages, which is why you have to specify this information yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sorry that it should have been clear if I had read it.